# Php GD непонятные символы

Tags: php

Помогите разобрать откуда непонятные символы на изображении, текст формирую таким образом:

```
$text = strip_tags($qqqtext);

$text = substr($text, 0, 140). "...";

$text = wordwrap($text, 60, "\n", 2);

$text1 = $qqqtext2;

ImageTTFtext($pic, 14, 0, $w, $h, $color1, "arial.ttf", $text);

ImageTTFtext($pic, 13.3, 0, $w1, $h1, $color, "arial.ttf", $text1);
```

**А в конце изображения у меня вот такой символ: Ð**

Может кто то сталкивался?
Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Глупость какая-то, указываю нечетное число в 

 $text = substr($text, 0, 145). "...";

все нормально

если четное 

$text = substr($text, 0, 150). "..."; - то появляется  Ð

Comment: Ну проблемы чёт/нечет в substr как бы намекают на то, что Вы выдираете часть символа из кодировки в несколько байт (например из utf8)

Answer (score 1):

Функция substr работает, по факту, с байтами. Русские буквы кодируются несколькими байтами, поэтому в результате строка режется не по символам, а по частям символов, и "часть символа" в этом случае декодируется как совершенно иной символ.

Для работы со строками в посимвольном режиме вам нужна функция [mb_substr](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php) (дословно: multibyte substring) и знание кодировки, в которой вы работаете.